# How to create a Android Market Link for listing all apps from the developer?

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to add a button in my app saying "more apps" which opens the Android Market App listing all my apps. I found a document here saying that the link should be market://search?q=pub:. However, it's NOT working. On Searching it returns no result. The link for HTTP:// works though, but I really want to use the market:// link.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that the problem is about formatting. The URL should be something like:

```
String MARKET = "market://search?q=pub:\"Developer Name\"";
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Intent goToMarket; 
goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:\"Developer name\"")); 
startActivity(goToMarket);
```

Comment: I have found a solution to this problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: it's like: String MARKET = "market://search?q=pub:\"Developer Name\"";